# Capistrano run in sequential mode

Tags: ssh, capistrano

I was wondering is there is a way to specify to the `run` command of Capistrano a way to operate in sequential mode rather than in parallel (typically via an environment variable)
If possible, I would like to avoid a conditional statement to switch between a `run` call and a `find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |hostname| ... end` loop.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the correct syntax finally. You can limit the scope of a `run` command via the `:hosts` specifier (thanks [Andriy Yanko](http://railsware.com/blog/2011/11/02/advanced-server-definitions-in-capistrano/)). Example:

```
    before "mytask", 'set_roles'
    ########### mytask #####################
    desc "Example of a sequential run of capistrano"
    task :mytask, :roles => :dynhosts do
        find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |hostname|
             info "=> run mytask on #{hostname}"
             run "whoami", :hosts => [ "#{hostname}" ]
        end         
    end
```